# Adding if statement into the_content()

Tags: posts, pages, the-content

I've created my own page template where I have a list of posts coming in directly below the content as so:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>            
<?php query_posts('category_name=vacancies'); ?>
<ul>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>         
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
<?php // Reset Query
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

This works fine on this page, however on the main index page my template is set up so it loads in the_content() four different pages. I want to include this within one of them e.g:

if query_posts() exists in page then load into the_content() on index page

Bit confusing, hope I'm making sense, any ideas?

Comment: You're totally bastardizing the order of output here. The call to `the_content()` should *always* be **inside** the Loop. And calls to `query_posts()` should only ever be used to modify the **Primary** Loop. If you need to query additional posts, you should use `WP_Query()` or `get_posts()`. That said: **can you describe, in human - not code - terms, what you are trying to accomplish with each template file ( `page.php` and `index.php`)?**

Comment: Ok no problem, I know its a tad confusing lol. Template page.php (a template I created) - I want the content to show and a list of posts to show below it. That works with the code I wrote. Index page - load in the template page content and list of posts (without affecting other pages that load in).

Comment: Basically I fixed up my template page with the code below. Now I want all the content and posts list to be displayed on index page, not just the content from the template.

Comment: The `page.php` template file has a [specific purpose in the WordPress Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Page_display). Generally speaking, you should **not load the `page.php` template file *inside* the `index.php` template file - or inside any other template file, for that matter**. Also, really still haven't explained, in human terms, what you're trying to accomplish. If you can do that, we can help you.

Comment: Yeah I know I'm probably not explaining this well, sorry. I'm using a WordPress theme that loads content from 3 selected pages into the homepage. I want it so that for one of these pages (the one with the list) it doesn't just load in the content, it loads in the content **and** list. So how can I append the list to the content (if possible)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how your code works BUT I do know this. If you only have one loop on the page-template you could use `query_posts();` but if you have more than 1 loop it will screw up the code, even if you reset it. I would recommend you to use `WP_Query` like this:

```
<?php
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query('category_name=vacancies');
if($the_query) echo '<ul>';
// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
?>

<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php       
endwhile;
if($the_query) echo '</ul>';
// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

[WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: On my page template I only have the one loop that's why it was working fine. If your way is the more correct way of doing it of course I'll use it! I wasn't aware of this...

Comment: You could put if($the_query){the_content();} as well. So it is possible to detect query_posts / wp_query :)